# Problem when visiting users profiles

Tags: theming, users

In my website, users can connect, see their profiles, update their profiles and **visit other users profiles**

So for each users, I created a profile page `user-profile.tpl.php`

But I've some troubles when I'm visiting other users account.

For example in my account profile page, there is a link who's redirecting me to the edit page.

I wrote this code for showing the edit link :

```
<?php
  global $user;
  print l(t('Update my profile'), "user/{$GLOBALS['user']->uid}/edit");
?>
```

When I'm visiting a random user page, this link appears. **But I want it to appear only on my profile page**

And it's the same for my profile picture, when I'm visiting a random user page, my picture is always showing.

```
<?php 
    $user_item = user_load_by_name($user->name); // or user_load( $user->uid )
    print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user_item));
?>
```

I have no idea how to fix theses problems, that's why I need your help (I'm new to Drupal btw)

(I'm using Profile2)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user id from url using `arg()` function. for the first part you can do something like this.

```
global $user;
$user_id = arg(1);
if($user->uid == $user_id) {
// means it is logged in user profile - so show edit link


}
```

For the second part you are loading profile of logged in user, that is why it is always showing your picture you need to do the following instead.

```
$user_item = user_load($user_id); // user id we got from arg()
print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user_item));
```